# Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/is-array' in '/snapshot/frontend/node_modules/next-server/dist/lib'

Tags: next.js, zeit-pkg

Can someone check this...

I really need help, because I'm stuck

https://github.com/MustansirZia/next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate/issues/10

Thanks in advance
Carlos Vieira

```
pkg app.js 
> pkg@4.4.0
> Targets not specified. Assuming:
  node10-linux-x64, node10-macos-x64, node10-win-x64
shintaro@shintaro-PC:~/Desktop/projects/github/frontend$ ./app-linux 
> Using "webpackDevMiddleware" config function defined in next.config.js.
[ error ] /snapshot/frontend/node_modules/next-server/dist/lib/loadable.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/is-array' in '/snapshot/frontend/node_modules/next-server/dist/lib'
I think its a problem of pkg that isn't loading the modules...
pleaase this boilerplate is really helpufll...
```

Comment: can you make a reproduction repo

Comment: thanks for the reply
please check
https://github.com/ShintaroNippon/next-express-bootstrap-boilerplate
run npm install -g pkg
&&
 pkg app.js -t node10-linux-x64 -o frontend

&&
/frontend 
> Using "webpackDevMiddleware" config function defined in next.config.js.
[ error ] /snapshot/next/node_modules/next-server/dist/lib/loadable.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime-corejs2/core-js/array/is-array' in '/snapshot/next/node_modules/next-server/dist/lib'